# Python app crashes when emit signal from callback

Tags: python, callback, crash, signals, pyside

I use my c++ library from python application with QT. It uses callback to communicate with UI.
My library is 'ts'. The problem is that my program crashes sometimes.
As I understood it crashes when call to emit(), but it happens rarely.
The simplified version of my program looks like this:

```
import ts
...
class Parser(QObject):

    sig = Signal(ts.ProgramDescriptions)

    ts = ts.Ts()

    def init(self):
        self.ts.SetProgramChangeCB(SetProgramListCB)

    ...

class Ui_Dialog(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, pars):
        self.parser = pars
    ...

def SetProgramListCB(programDesc):
    print "SetProgramListCB"
    ui.parser.sig.emit(programDesc)



def SetProgramList(programDesc):
    print "SetProgramList"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QDialog()

    parser = Parser()
    parser.init()
    parser.sig.connect(SetProgramList, Qt.QueuedConnection)

    parser.Start()

    ui = Ui_Dialog(parser)


    ...
```

Help!

Comment: This is just the surrounding GUI code, which is extremely unlikely to produce crashes. It sounds very much like the problem is either in your library or in `ui.ravisParser.sig.emit`. You should run the program under a debugger to get detailed information about the crash - what is it's immediate cause (like, a memory read on an invalid address - which one?)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was inattantive, and made some mistakes while publishing source code. Now I corrected it.
I am novice in python so I don't know how to run my app under debugger. Can you recommend me debugger. My OS is Win7.

Comment: This edit clarifies a little bit, but the question still contains only the GUI code, and not the one in `parser`, which is likely at fault. Any debugger will do, for example [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009).

Comment: Parser - is simple wrapper arround c++ library which calls provided in ts.SetProgramChangeCB() callback.

The debugger show me this when app crashed:
(2e4.13a0): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(2e4.13a0): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=032eeb34 ebx=004337b8 ecx=00000003 edx=00000000 esi=77ee057c edi=032eebc4
eip=75acd36f esp=032eeb34 ebp=032eeb84 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000212
...

Comment: Does this means that I have non-catched exception somwhere?

Comment: When crash I have only "SetProgramListCB" printed on screen, but not "SetProgramList".

Comment: Yes, but it's a C++ exception, not a Python one - just like I predicted ;)

Comment: Maybe it is QT exception? 
Because "SetProgramListCB" is printed, but not "SetProgramList"

Answer (score 0):

After finding out that the cause of crash is C++ exception (with help of phihag), I changed my code in this way, and that fixed the problem:

```
def SetProgramListCB(programDesc):        
    try:
        print ui.ravisParser.sig
        ui.ravisParser.sig.emit(programDesc)
    except:
        print "Error"
```

In case of proper work I have (output):

```
<PySide.QtCore.Signal object at 0x01DD88C0>
<PySide.QtCore.Signal object at 0x01DD88C0>
<PySide.QtCore.Signal object at 0x01DD88C0>
...
```

And in case of Error:

```
Error
<PySide.QtCore.Signal object at 0x01DD88C0>
<PySide.QtCore.Signal object at 0x01DD88C0>
<PySide.QtCore.Signal object at 0x01DD88C0>
...
```

So the reason why it crashed was that in first call to emit() signal 'sig' was not initialized.
I can't understand how it could happen, because callback is called from thread which starts when call to 'parser.Start()' which called **after** connect signal 'sig' :

```
parser.sig.connect(SetProgramList, Qt.QueuedConnection)

parser.Start()
```